# Different box plots on the same oX position

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, visualization

I am trying to combine box plots with a scatter plot for an algorithm scoring visualization. My data is divided as following:

- oX - information about the time period (1 year, 2 years, etc.)
- oY - information about the score
- 2 algorithms for each period with different simulation results (plotted as boxplots)
- 2 heuristics with a single value (plotted as a point)

I'm trying to easily compare method efficiency for each period of time.

Small sample data:

```
1 year              2 years         
A1  A2  H1  H2  A1  A2  H1  H2
124 168 155 167 130 130 150 164
102 155         100 172     
103 153         117 145     
102 132         145 143     
145 170         133 179     
136 125         115 153     
116 150         136 131     
146 192         106 148     
124 122         127 158     
128 123         149 200     
141 158         137 156
```

I'm trying to get something that looks like this:
[image]

So far I've cleared up my data to have the observations for each algorithm (RS, EA) and for each period (52, 104, 156 etc.) separately [**like so**](https://gyazo.com/9a39bf201bb2c960b3ae677fce403e51) but I can't figure out how to group them per period while drawing 2 different boxplots for the same X tick. I assume once I'd sort out the boxplot dataframe and plot, I can just plot the scatter on top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve this meanwhile, in case it helps anyone else out:

```
ax1 = sns.boxplot(data = meta, x = 'Time', y = 'PRS', color = '#880BDD', linewidth=0.8)
ax1 = sns.boxplot(data = meta, x = 'Time', y = 'EA', color = '#0BC9DD', linewidth=0.8)
ax1 = sns.boxplot(data = meta, x = 'Time', y = 'ERS', color = '#9BD19D', linewidth=0.8)
ax1 = sns.pointplot(data = simple, x = 'Time', y = 'Greedy Average', color='#FFC48C', markers ='s', join=False)
ax1 = sns.pointplot(data = simple, x = 'Time', y = 'Greedy Total', color='#FF9F80', markers='o', join=False)
ax1 = sns.pointplot(data = simple, x = 'Time', y = 'Greedy Weeks', color='#F56991', markers='*', join=False)
ax1.set(xlabel = "Planning Horizon (weeks)")
ax1.set(ylabel = "Hypervolume")
EA = mpatches.Patch(color='#0BC9DD', label = 'EA')
PRS = mpatches.Patch(color='#880BDD', label = 'PRS')
ERS = mpatches.Patch(color='#9BD19D', label = 'ERS')
GA = mlines.Line2D([], [], color='#FFC48C', marker = 's', label = 'Greedy Average')
GT = mlines.Line2D([], [],color='#FF9F80', label = 'Greedy Total', marker = 'o')
GW = mlines.Line2D([], [],color='#F56991', label = 'Greedy Weeks', marker = '*')
plt.legend(handles = [EA, ERS, PRS, GA, GT, GW], loc = 'bottom left', title = "Algorithm")
ax1.set_title("Algorithm Comparison")
```

Results in this:

[image]